# Change the way a service starts

Tags: 14.04, services

I have the Solr service running currently. I wish to run Solr Cloud.

According to [this article](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud), I need to execute the command:

```
$ bin/solr -e cloud
```

I know how to stop the service and how to start the service. There are many questions and answers that have described it well.

My question is how do I change the service to start with the above command? As in, currently, I assume that the service starts without the `- e cloud` arguments. How do I change or update the solr service so that it starts with the above arguments?

Comment: How do you start or stop the service?

Comment: Or let us know the version of Ubuntu you're running: It depends on that...

Comment: @muru `sudo service solr start / stop`

Comment: @Fabby Using 14.04. Updated tag.